# Cancelling an OTA download for an update causes my application's icon to vanish from the device

Tags: blackberry, ota

I have a BlackBerry applications that user download OTA.  If they already have the application installed and browse to my download page, the download button (with a link to the JAD file) works and lets them download a new version that replaces the existing version.

The problem I'm having is when the user starts the download (sees the progress bar moving) and then cancels it before completion.  In this case, the icon for my application vanishes from the device, even though the COD file is still present on the device.

How can I prevent this from happening, or is this normal for a BlackBerry?  It seems totally contrary to what any user would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our customers have started reporting this recently as well. A restart of the device (pulling the battery), will restore the icon.

This began occurring with recent RIM OS versions, and is common on recent devices,

It can happen with fully-completed OTA downloads as well as half-cancelled ones, and can even be influenced by the active theme on the device.

We tell our customers to simply reboot the device if they find that the application is "missing" after an update OTA download, and it seems to work.

Comment: My next question: how is RIM still in business with this kind of thing going on? I guess things like this are kind of minor in the grand scheme of things, when compared with the signing server catastrophe.

Comment: :) We've been writing software for BlackBerry devices going back to SDK 4.1 (black and white screens, etc) -- believe me, this isn't the first, nor the worst we've seen.

Comment: I've investigated this more, and the situation is terrible. On my Curve 9330 (5.0), the icon vanishes and doesn't return even after I pull the battery (although it's still listed in the applications list, and I can start it from there). Weirdly, though, I can't find much mention of this problem online at all. Are BB users just accustomed to always doing what the download dialogs tell them to do?

Comment: Well. Every platform has its quirks. But yeah, generally, there's always a few of these bugs with every RIM OS update. As a developer on the platform, we've often had to be the sounding board for our customers because of things like this. There isn't much choice other than to find a workaround (of which there is often none), or to wait it out (usually until the next wave of devices ship).

Comment: We're expecting 100,000+ users of our app. I'm sure I'm going to be hit with every possible thing that can go wrong.